# Array .Push not adding to end of Array

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

When editing a cell and logging the output of the Array, PUSH function has not added the newly edited cell to the end of the array; it only outputs one element, almost as though it's recreating the array each time you edit a cell.

```js
var EnteredDates = [];

function OnEdit(e){
var range = e.range;

EnteredDates.push([range.getValue(),range.getA1Notation()]);

}
```

I've tried searching the stack overflow questions. but can't see this exact problem of an array being re-created when pushing.

I've also tried initiating the Array as a Global variable and also, instead, initiated it inside OnOpen Function. Both don't work.

Additionally I've also removed initiating it as a Global Variable incase it is always being initiated on code being run and tried the following; when logging the EnteredDates array it still only shows the latest entry.

```js
if (!Array.isArray(EnteredDates)) {
   var EnteredDates = [];
}
                
EnteredDates.push([range.getValue(),range.getA1Notation()]);
Logger.log(EnteredDates);
```

Comment: where is code ?

Comment: Do you have code? My guess is that you are expecting push to return the new array but it doesn't. It only returns the length of the new array. The original array is modified.

Comment: `initiated it inside OnOpen Function` -> It seems like every time the function is called the array is set to empty array i:e `arrayName = []`, which will delete already inserted elements and re initiate to empty array.

Comment: Provide code if you want a precise answer.

Comment: Sorry guys, I'm not sure what happened with the website; I thought i entered the code. PLease refresh you'll see it now. Very simple.. just a Push function in OnEdit

Answer (score 3):

> an array being re-created when pushing

as already mentioned by @ktilcu, this is not the case with `.push()`, the original array is modified, no new array is created.

Lacking any code example in your question I assume you're doing something like this:

```js
var cells = ['cell 1', 'cell 2', 'cell 3'];

console.log(cells.push('cell 4'));
```

the console logs `4`, which is the `length` of the modified array, not the array itself or the item you just pushed to it, e.g. it's kind of the same as if you would do:

```js
var cells = ['cell 1', 'cell 2', 'cell 3'];

cells.push('cell 4');

console.log(cells.length)
```

to actually "see" the modified array, you would have to do something like this:

```js
var cells = ['cell 1', 'cell 2', 'cell 3'];

cells.push('cell 4');

console.log(cells);
```

Comment: @Phil...Just wanted to point out `let` declaration is not supported by Google Apps Script.

Comment: I've tried actually initiating a new array globally above all the code AND

I've also tried initiating a new array (var EnteredDates = [];) within the OnOpen function.

Comment: The above coding is what I'm doing, I'm referring to the Array 'EnteredDates' to output the array in the Logger.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems getting global array to work.  So I used the following instead.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()!='Sheet177')return;
  pushArray(e.value + "," + e.range.getA1Notation());
  e.source.toast(e.value + ', ' + e.range.getA1Notation());
}

function pushArray(value) {
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('array', PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('array') + ',' + value)
}

function getArray() {
  return PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('array');
}

function runOne() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(getArray());
}

function runTwo() {
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('array', '');
}
```

runOne and runTwo are functions that are builtin to my menu so using those function names keeps me from having to add them to my menu all of the time.

Comment: Thanks; Can you elaborate on what the coding is doing. Are you saying that Push does not work or is not the way you push to an array if you want to use it in OnEdit?

Comment: I don't know.  I might guess that the trigger doesn't have access to global scope, but I really don't know.

Comment: I've thought about this some more and I think that the real problem is that the global declaration gets executed on every onEdit(e) function call.